# Estimated pricing for CloudKit usage?

Tags: cloudkit

I have a series of questions all for CloudKit pricing, hence a single post with multiple questions as they are all interrelated.

---

The current CloudKit calculator (as of Feb 2017) shows the following pricing details for 100,000 users:

[image]

Imagine working on an application which has large assets and large amount of data transfer (even after using compression and architecting it such that transfers are minimized).

---

Now, assume my actual numbers for an app such as the one I just described with 100,000 users is:

- Asset Storage: 7.5 TB
- Data Transfer: 375 TB (this looks pretty high, but assume it is true)

**My Questions**

- Then will the `Data Transfer` component of my usage bill will be: (375 - 5) * 1000 GB * 0.10 $/GB = 37000 $?
- Also, are there some pricing changes if say one is within the 5TB limit, but exceeds the `50MB per user` limit or is that per user limit just an average, so even if the data transfer per user may be higher than 50MB, but if I stay within 5TB limit, I won't be charged?
- What does Active Users really mean in this pricing context? The number of users who have downloaded the app or the number of users using the app in a given month?
- How is the asset storage counted? Imagine for 2 successive months, this is the asset size uploaded: Month 1: 7.5 TB, Month 2: 7.5 TB. Then in the second month, will my asset storage be counted as 15 TB or 7.5 TB?
- Is it correct that asset storage etc allocations increase for every user that is added (the screenshot does say that) or the allocations are increased in bulk only when you hit certain numbers such as: 10K, 20K, .., 100K etc? I read about bulk allocation but cannot find the source now and I am asking this question just to be sure, to avoid unpleasant surprises later.
- Last but not the least, is CloudKit usage billed monthly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, but really a support question for Apple to answer (https://developer.apple.com/contact/)